# How to read file from a folder that has many sub-folders

Tags: bash, directory, navigation

I have a data directory has has three sub-directories and each sub-directory has three different sub-directories. And I need to read two different files from the last sub-directory. How can I accomplish this?

I tried this using the below code and I am not able to navigate through all the sub-directories.

```
cd $datadir

for dirs in *;

    do

    cd $dirs

    
        for folders in *; 

            do 

            echo $folders; 


            file1=$(find "$folders" -name '*regADNI.nii.gz');
            file2=$(find "$folders" -name '*0.25mm-Crop.nii.gz');

            echo $file1
            echo $file2 

            fname=$(echo "$file1" | sed 's|\(.*\)/.*|\1|');
            #echo $fname

            echo "***************"
            
        done

    cd .
    pwd
```

Following is the folder organization

[image]

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks
Anandh.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit easier if you don't `cd` around while trying to do this.  It makes sense to try, but it just gets a bit messy when you need to manage where you are in a script; moving up/down directories all the time.

I'd recommend instead building up the file paths that you need to search, and then using `find` on those directories without moving. For example:

```bsh
for topDir in $(ls -d ./a*/); do
    for subDir in $(ls -d $topDir*/); do
        for leafDir in $(ls -d $subDir*/); do
            echo "Dir  : $leafDir"
            file1=$(find "$leafDir" -name '1.gz')
            file2=$(find "$leafDir" -name '2.gz')
            echo "Files:" $file1 $file2
        done
    done
done
```

The script above does 3 loops, building up the directories to search from listings of only directories in each previous directly.  Executed on the directory structure below:

```
justin@mal:~$ tree a
a
├── a
│   ├── a
│   │   ├── 1.gz
│   │   └── 2.gz
│   ├── b
│   │   ├── 1.gz
│   │   └── 2.gz
│   └── c
├── b
│   ├── a
│   │   ├── 1.gz
│   │   └── 2.gz
│   ├── b
│   │   └── 1.gz
│   └── c
│       ├── 1.gz
│       └── 2.gz
└── c
    ├── a
    ├── b
    └── c
        ├── 1.gz
        └── 2.gz

12 directories, 11 files
```

gives

```
justin@mal:~$ bash script 
Dir  : ./a/a/a/
Files: ./a/a/a/1.gz ./a/a/a/2.gz
Dir  : ./a/a/b/
Files: ./a/a/b/1.gz ./a/a/b/2.gz
Dir  : ./a/a/c/
Files:
Dir  : ./a/b/a/
Files: ./a/b/a/1.gz ./a/b/a/2.gz
Dir  : ./a/b/b/
Files: ./a/b/b/1.gz
Dir  : ./a/b/c/
Files: ./a/b/c/1.gz ./a/b/c/2.gz
Dir  : ./a/c/a/
Files:
Dir  : ./a/c/b/
Files:
Dir  : ./a/c/c/
Files: ./a/c/c/1.gz ./a/c/c/2.gz
```

You should be able to adapt this to your specific top-level directory name and file name structures without too much trouble (switch out the top `a` folder and the file1, file2 names).  Hope this helps.